# Do any FLOSS projects utilize human input for speech synthesis?

Tags: open-source, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Are there any open source, open content projects that use recorded speech data to generate synthesized speech? (With the goal of synthesising/simulating the speech of a particular individual. As a side note, is there a name for this process, goal or the data extracted? "voice signature"?)

I imagine the workflow would be something like:

- record speech from standardized text ("The teddy sat on the mat.")
- pick out phonemes ("a" of cat), accounting for accent
- get the data that makes Alice's "eh" sound different to Betty's "eh"
- render text to speech using accent-appropriate phonemes plus voice signature

Answering this question is a critical step in petitioning [Jack Angel](http://www.jackangel.tv) ([Teddy](http://film-take.blogspot.com/2009/10/people-look-for-ai-teddy-bear-toy.html), [Wonkers](http://tlj.wikia.com/wiki/Wonkers)) to donate his soothing voice signature to the public domain for the sake of humanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [open source project called festvox](http://festvox.org/transform/transform.html) sponsored by Carnegie Mellon University that has a goal of synthesized voice built on a particular speaker.  There concept is described here and it sounds like a very time consuming process to get it tuned correctly.  There is a good list of Text-To-Speech open source projects on [BableFish.org](http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm).  There is a good discussion on [Text To Speech Blog](http://www.texttospeechblog.com/2008/07/creating-your-own-voice.html) about building a TTS engine around a particular speaker.